# how to remove collision objects from Rviz by code

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering if a function able to remove collision objects from world do exists...

because the

> `planning_scene_interface.removeCollisionObjects(object_ids)`

function requires at least 0.4/0.5 seconds delay to be effective on Rviz, but my target is to remove it istantaneously.
I know there was a similar issue with the placement of an object in the world, because also the function

> `addCollisionObjects`

requires that delay in order to be effective in Rviz. But this has been solved by using another function:

> `applyCollisionObject`

So if anyone has ever dealt with these things please try to help me. Thanks in advance.

ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu version 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302464/how-to-remove-collision-objects-from-rviz-by-code/) by [enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/34982/enrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-10-18**:
Also referenced in [this follow-up question](https://answers.ros.org/question/363681/after-removing-collision-objects-from-the-world-they-still-remain-in-rviz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `bool applyCollisionObject(const moveit_msgs::CollisionObject& collision_object);` by specifying  `collision_object.operation = collision_object.REMOVE;` when you create the `moveit_msgs::CollisionObject`

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2018-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1